# Save the anchorpoint position in Sketch 4

Tags: sketch-app, illustration

is there a way to reuse the same anchor point position on a layer multiple times or do i have to set the anchorpoint everytime i try to rotate the layer?

[image: example for multiple rotation layers]

So when i try to design that flowerlike graphic and i copy/paste the leafs i dont have to set the anchorpoint for every new rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that it is not a direct answer to this question but if you want to make such a geometric graphic like this, you can use [Looper](http://sureskumar.com/looper/) plugin.